# W3 Total Cache - Specify expiration time for each cached page

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have multiple pages one my site. Few of them are static, few are dynamic.

Is there a way to specify expiration time for cached pages?
I want static pages to be re-cached only once a day, dynamic a lot more often.

Comment: I guess you can use fragment cache for dynamic areas in your site. I am not sure about how to use fragment cache but if this hint can help you in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

URIs are only modified when updated so there is no benefit in setting different expiration times for different pages.